# Powershell - how to log for each object

Tags: powershell

I'm slowly getting to grips with Powershell but I cant see how to capture the for-each loop in a log (its probably something straight forward). My current code creates the log but doesnt seem to write to it - any ideas where I am going wrong?

```
$CSVImp = Import-Csv -Path "C:\Support\Powershell-Rename\Data.csv" 
$OutputLog = ".\output.log" 
Write $CSVImp | Where-Object { $_.CompName -eq $env:computername } | ForEach-Object {Rename-Item $_.FileLocation -NewName $_.FileRename -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue } | Out-File $OutputLog -Append
```

Thanks

Comment: `Rename-Item` doesn't output anything, what is it that you're hoping to write to your log?

Comment: The CSV holds the original file names path and also what I am re-naming the files to. This then changes the file names on the client and I am trying to log this change. Thanks

Comment: If I write-output I can see whats going on so is there a way to get this to a text file?

Answer (score 1):

The scriptblock you pass to `ForEach-Object` can have as many statements as you like:

```
... |ForEach-Object {
    Rename-Item $_.FileLocation -NewName $_.FileRename -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue 
    if($?){
        "[+] Successfully renamed '$($_.FileLocation)' to '$($_.FileRename)'"
    }
    else {
        "[!] Failed to rename '$($_.FileLocation)' to '$($_.FileRename)'"
    }
} |Out-File $OutputLog -Append
```

Comment: I saw your post just after I committed mine. I learned a new trick, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest something like this where you use a Try/Catch block to log your entries.

Updated re: Mathias' comment. Hope I got it right!

```
$CSVImp = Import-Csv -Path "C:\Support\Powershell-Rename\Data.csv" 
$OutputLog = ".\output.log" 
$CSVImp | Where-Object { $_.CompName -eq $env:computername } | 
          ForEach-Object {
            Try {
                  $MsgTrailer = "Rename $($_.FileLocation) to $($_.FileRename)"
                  Rename-Item $_.FileLocation -NewName $_.FileRename -ErrorAction Stop 
                  "Success: $MsgTrailer" | 
                       Out-File $OutputLog -Append
            }
            Catch {
             "Failed:  $MsgTrailer" | Out-File $OutputLog -Append
            }
```

Note: Untested code!

Comment: Very nice approach, but there's a gotcha here! Since you're explicitly catching the error, `$_` will refer to the error, not the input record. Re-assign `$renameOp = $_` or similar before hitting the `try` block to still have a reference to the original input object when you reach `catch` :)

Comment: Do you happen to have a sample code please? But I think I know what your saying. The error wont show the part thats failed?